envoyproxy listeners does not echo back
I wrote a simple TCP echo server and UDP echo server in Golang.
The main goal is to expose these two services behind envoyproxy.
Below the configuration I have written:
compose.yaml
services:
  envoy:
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:dev
    ports:
      - "10000:10000"
      - "9001:9001"
      - "9002:9002"
    volumes:
      - ./envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml
      - ./cds.yaml:/var/lib/envoy/cds.yaml
      - ./lds.yaml:/var/lib/envoy/lds.yaml
  echo-tcp:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-echo-tcp
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    volumes:
      - .:/tmp
  echo-udp:
      build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile-echo-udp
      ports:
        - 8082:8082
      volumes:
        - .:/tmp

envoy.yaml
node:
  cluster: civo-envoy-cluster
  id: civo-id

dynamic_resources:
  cds_config:
    resource_api_version: V3
    path: /var/lib/envoy/cds.yaml
  lds_config:
    resource_api_version: V3
    path: /var/lib/envoy/lds.yaml

admin:
  address:
    socket_address:
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 10000


cds.yaml
resources:
- "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.cluster.v3.Cluster
  name: civo_tcp_cluster
  load_assignment:
    cluster_name: civo_tcp_cluster
    endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 8081
- "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.cluster.v3.Cluster
  name: civo_udp_cluster
  load_assignment:
    cluster_name: civo_udp_cluster
    endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: 0.0.0.0
                port_value: 8082

lds.yaml

resources:
- "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener
  name: listener_tcp
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9001
  filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: filter_tcp
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.tcp_proxy.v3.TcpProxy
          cluster: civo_tcp_cluster
          stat_prefix: civo_stat_tcp
- "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.config.listener.v3.Listener
  name: listener_udp
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: UDP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9002
  filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: filter_udp
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.udp.udp_proxy.v3.UdpProxyConfig
          cluster: civo_udp_cluster
          stat_prefix: civo_stat_udp
  listener_filters:
    - name: envoy.filters.udp_listener.udp_proxy
      typed_config:
        '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.udp.udp_proxy.v3.UdpProxyConfig
        stat_prefix: civo_stat_udp
        matcher:
          on_no_match:
            action:
              name: udp_route
              typed_config:
                '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.udp.udp_proxy.v3.Route
                cluster: civo_udp_cluster

Dockerfile-echo-tcp
FROM golang:1.22.2 as builder

WORKDIR /opt
COPY tcp/tcp.go .
COPY tcp/go.mod .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o tcp tcp.go

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=builder /opt/tcp .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/tcp" ]
EXPOSE 8081

Dockerfile-echo-udp
FROM golang:1.22.2 as builder

WORKDIR /opt
COPY udp/udp.go .
COPY udp/go.mod .
RUN CGO_ENABLED=0 GOOS=linux go build -a -installsuffix cgo -o udp udp.go

FROM scratch
WORKDIR /opt
COPY --from=builder /opt/udp .
ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/udp" ]
EXPOSE 8082

tcp.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    ln, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8081")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Listen(): %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for {

        conn, err := ln.Accept()
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Accept(): %s\n", err)
            continue
        }

        reader, writer := bufio.NewReader(conn), bufio.NewWriter(conn)

        go func() {

            buffer := make([]byte, 1024)
            reader.Read(buffer)
            writer.Write(buffer)
        }()
    }
}


udp.go
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "net"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    addr, _ := net.ResolveUDPAddr("udp", "0.0.0.0:8082")
    ln, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Listen(): %s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    reader, writer := bufio.NewReader(ln), bufio.NewWriter(ln)
    buffer := make([]byte, 1024)

    for {
        reader.Read(buffer)
        writer.Write(buffer)
    }
}

envoy.logs
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][filter] [source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:264] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] new tcp proxy session
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:401] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] readDisable: disable=true disable_count=0 state=0 buffer_length=0
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][filter] [source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:459] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] Creating connection to cluster civo_tcp_cluster
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][misc] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:2269] Allocating TCP conn pool
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:291] trying to create new connection
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:292] ConnPoolImplBase 0x25fc7fc2a280, ready_clients_.size(): 0, busy_clients_.size(): 0, connecting_clients_.size(): 0, connecting_stream_capacity_: 0, num_active_streams_: 0, pending_streams_.size(): 1 per upstream preconnect ratio: 1
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:145] creating a new connection (connecting=0)
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:1017] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] connecting to 0.0.0.0:8081
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:1036] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] connection in progress
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:131] not creating a new connection, shouldCreateNewConnection returned false.
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:469] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] raising connection event 2
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][filter] [source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:806] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] on downstream event 2, has upstream = false
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][conn_handler] [source/common/listener_manager/active_tcp_listener.cc:160] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] new connection from 172.20.0.1:35208
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][misc] [source/common/network/tcp_listener_impl.cc:114] TcpListener accepted 1 new connections.
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:614] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] socket event: 2
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:737] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] write ready
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:614] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] socket event: 3
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:737] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] write ready
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:757] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] delayed connect error: 111
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:276] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] closing socket: 0
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:469] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] raising connection event 0
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:495] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"2"] client disconnected, failure reason: delayed connect error: 111
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][filter] [source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:459] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] Creating connection to cluster civo_tcp_cluster
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:150] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] closing data_to_write=0 type=1
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:276] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] closing socket: 1
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][connection] [source/common/network/connection_impl.cc:469] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] raising connection event 1
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][filter] [source/common/tcp_proxy/tcp_proxy.cc:806] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] on downstream event 1, has upstream = false
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][conn_handler] [source/common/listener_manager/active_stream_listener_base.cc:126] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] tcp connection on event 1
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][conn_handler] [source/common/listener_manager/active_stream_listener_base.cc:136] [Tags: "ConnectionId":"1"] adding to cleanup list
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:228] item added to deferred deletion list (size=1)
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:228] item added to deferred deletion list (size=2)
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:131] not creating a new connection, shouldCreateNewConnection returned false.
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:228] item added to deferred deletion list (size=3)
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][debug][pool] [source/common/conn_pool/conn_pool_base.cc:463] invoking 1 idle callback(s) - is_draining_for_deletion_=false
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][upstream] [source/common/upstream/cluster_manager_impl.cc:2151] Idle pool, erasing pool for host 0.0.0.0:8081
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.035][37][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:228] item added to deferred deletion list (size=4)
envoy-1     | [2024-06-07 09:51:14.036][37][trace][main] [source/common/event/dispatcher_impl.cc:122] clearing deferred deletion list (size=4)


The connection was made with netcat with nc -4 127.0.0.1 9001
The UDP datagram was sent with netcat with echo 'Hello from netcat!' | nc -4 -u 127.0.0.1 9002 but nothing is logged
What I am doing wrong ?
I am expecting that when a TCP connection is made and I send a payload, the payload is echoed back.
Same behaviour for UDP, datagrams must be echoed back.
Gianluca
